# PHP inside an HTML Attribute

Tags: php, html, html5-video, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to set the poster image of an HTML Video via PHP, but no luck so far.

```
 <video class="friend-video" width="100%" poster="<?php the_sub_field('thumbnail_select'); ?>" muted loop>
```

Does anyone know how I could make this work?
I'm using Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: What is the actual output in your `poster` attribute?

Comment: In ACF the field type is set to "URL". So the field contains the URL of the Image.

Comment: poster="<?php the_sub_field('thumbnail_select'); ?>"    ->  poster="/<?php echo the_sub_field('thumbnail_select'); ?>"      in case the name is eg "/nameposter.gif"   check whatever that function output first then do the modify is need

Comment: @Constantin that sounds like the correct Answer. Why not post it?

Comment: @timejumpone Did using `poster="<?php echo the_sub_field('thumbnail_select'); ?>"` solve the problem for you?